# Are <textarea> properties `.childNodes[0].nodeValue` and `.value` always equal?

Tags: javascript, textarea

Is it guaranteed, that if `textarea` is `HTMLTextAreaElement` then

```
textarea.childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

and

```
textarea.value
```

are always equal?

Usually it is true:

```js
let textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
let first = textarea.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
let second = textarea.value;
console.log(first === second);
```

```html
<textarea>
leters: 123
nbsp: &nbsp;
amp: &amp;
tabs: 1  2 3
</textarea>
```

---

Note, that `<textarea>` has exactly one child node (of type `TextNode`):

```js
let textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
console.log(textarea.childNodes);
```

```html
<textarea>text</textarea>
```

Comment: textarea does not have childNodes. so childNodes[0] returns undefined. So, attempting to get nodeValue on that would throw an error.

Comment: @Prashant, afaik it is false and textarea have exactly one child node (of type `TextNode`). Please see update to answer. Also if `textarea.childNodes` returns undefined then first snippet would not working, however it works.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if at all, it would be equivalent to `.defaultValue`. The `.value` changes dynamically.

Comment: @Bergi, yes, you are right, thanks a lot!

Comment: There is a difference between i.e. Chrome and Edge browsers. Edge uses child text node and Chrome does not. But if you explicitly create element with the child text node, i.e. `<textarea>xxx</textarea>` both browsers will have the same structure.